# Inexplicable Numpy nan's in np.sqrt() or np.arctan()

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have two data sets, data1 and data2. I am taking these data sets and performing this operation:

```
Out=np.arctan(np.sqrt(data1/data2))
```

There are three elements in Out that have the value nan when they really shouldn't be. I have the indices of the these nan elements saved in a list called `nanind`. So:

```
Out[nanind[0]]==nan
Out[nanind[1]]==nan
Out[nanind[2]]==nan
```

Now here is the part that has me really confused.

```
np.arctan(np.sqrt(data1[nanind[0]]/data2[nanind[0]))
np.arctan(np.sqrt(data1[nanind[1]]/data2[nanind[1]))
np.arctan(np.sqrt(data1[nanind[2]]/data2[nanind[2]))
```

do not return nan. They return positive floating point numbers as expected. Can anyone explain this, I really need Out to be free of nan elements?

P.S.  I have also tried doing this one element at a time in the form:

```
for i in range(data1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data1.shape[1]):
        Out[i,j]=np.arctan(np.sqrt(data1[i,j]/data2[i,j]))
```

and `Out` still has the same three elements that are nan.

Comment: Can you show values which return Nan?

Comment: Can you take your code apart into smaller steps?  Test for exceptional conditions between steps (`if math.isnan(result1):`) and print warnings or throw exceptions. Guessing games are unproductive, we need data and/ code.

Comment: Read [Chapter 8: Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#) of the Python docs, especially 8.4/8.5 for throwing your own exceptions, if you've never had to do this before.  Be sure to print an informative error message, like `"Unexpected sqrt value, input somevar="+str(somevar)+", sqrt was NaN"`

Comment: Write unit tests… That's all… Unit tests will make you think about the outcome and ensure every single step to be clear and safe.

Comment: I note that `np.sqrt(-1)` is `nan` not `0+1j`.  To get a complex value instead of nan, one can use `np.sqrt(-1+0j)` to get `1j`

Answer (score 2):

`np.sqrt()` returns `NaN` for negative input.

```
>>> np.sqrt([-1,2,3])
array([        nan,  1.41421356,  1.73205081])
```

On wrong type, like np.sqrt('hello'), it raises a TypeError

If mathematically permissible for your application, you can allow np.sqrt() to pass complex numbers out to the next step by passing complex numbers in.  This can be as simple as adding `0j` to a float like so:

```
>>> x = -1
>>> np.sqrt(x)
nan
>>> np.sqrt(x+0j)
1j
```

Otherwise, you should be testing the output of np.sqrt with `np.isnan`, possibly combined with `any` for testing over an array, and printing appropriate warnings or raising exceptions.

```
>>> np.isnan(np.sqrt([-1,2,3]))
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)

>>> np.isnan(np.sqrt([-1,2,3])).any()
True

step = np.sqrt(inputArray)
if np.isnan(step).any():
    # do something to report the error
    badItems = np.where(np.isnan(step))
    print "bad inputs at :"+str(badItems)
    print "bad input values: "+str(inputArray[np.isnan(step)])
    raise Exception("unexpected nans in sqrt step")
```

This is not the best way to write an exception for permanent code, but will work for debugging.  To learn more about exception handling, see [Python Docs, Chapter 8: Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#)